# Animation for collapsible block with cookie

Tags: jquery, animation, block, collapsable

I almost don't know javascript.
Can someone help me make animation for collapsible block?

---

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#hideButton');
    //check the cookie when the page loads
    if ($.cookie('currentToggle') === 'hidden') {
        togglePanel(button, false);
    }
    else {
        togglePanel(button, true);
    }
    //handle the clicking of the show/hide toggle button
    button.click(function() {
        //toggle the panel as required, base on current state
        if (button.text() === "+Показать блок контента") {
            togglePanel($(this), true);
        }
        else {
            togglePanel($(this), false);
        }
    });
});
function togglePanel(button, show) {
    var panel = $('#KeywordsPanel');
    if (show) {
        panel.removeClass('hidden');
        button.text('-Скрыть блок контента');
        $.cookie('currentToggle', '', { path: '/' });
    }
    else {
        panel.addClass('hidden');
        button.text('+Показать блок контента');
        $.cookie('currentToggle', 'hidden', { path: '/' });
    }
}
```

This is what I have at the moment - [http://jsfiddle.net/HbPF5](http://jsfiddle.net/HbPF5/)

Answer (score 0):

where you have panel.removeClass('hidden'); and panel.addClass('hidden');

you can replace them with jQuery show and hide methods and optionally include a speed

eg

```
panel.hide('slow');
```

and

```
panel.show('slow');
```

other effects can be used, jQuery docs page here: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Answer (score 0):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HbPF5/2/)

Try jQuery's slideDown & slideUp methods:

```
$(panel).slideDown('slow');
```

and

```
$(panel).slideUp('slow');
```

Note: You also don't need to add or remove display class with this.